# How can I select tuples based on a specific part of string input

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL to perform this operation. For example I want to select phone numbers that do not begin with '456'. What is the query to get tuples where the number does not **begin** with 456 and does not appear any where else.

I tried `WHERE phone NOT LIKE '%456%'` but that deselects all numbers with 456 in them.

[image: List of phone numbers]

List of phone numbers

[image: Result I got]

Result I got. This removes all numbers with 456 in them. Not just ones at the beginning

Comment: `WHERE phone NOT LIKE '456%'` -- leave out the first `%`.

Comment: That does not work, it makes no changes in the table. I think all values are 456% basically

Comment: None of your phone numbers begin with `456`, they all begin with `1-`.

Comment: Please add the sample data and the expected result as text not as image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your phone numbers begin with `456`, they all begin with `1-`. It seems like you want to check if the second part of the number is `456`, not the beginning. So use

```
WHERE number NOT LIKE '%-456-%'
```